# Drupal: Use separate theme for a front page

Tags: php, drupal

How to use separate theme for a front page and quite different theme for the other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module, that allows setting different themes to given paths (you can use the  path to target the frontpage).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a completely separate theme, you can also override the front page template (`page-front.tpl.php`) in your current theme. I'm not saying that you should never use a separate front page theme, but overriding the template is often an easier solution with less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Context module.